# Show Mercurial commits modifying a piece of code (multiple lines)

Tags: version-control, mercurial, revision-history

So suppose I have a piece of code consisting of several consecutive lines in a file and I want to find all the commits in the history which impacted this piece of code. Is there a way to do this with mercurial?

I don't mean with a single builtin command, because AFAIK Mercurial doesn't provide a command for this, so this probably needs a small script involving several commands.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to start with `hg blame`.  That will give you the most recent revision which altered each line.  You can then use the `-r` option to `hg blame` to walk backwards through history.

Any number of text processing programs can extract the revision numbers from `blame` and automate this process.

Answer (score 0):

If you know any immutable part of string(s) over the history, you can try, instead of blame in cycle (and some logic inside), use `hg grep --all ...` (PATTERN can be regexp, not just ordinary text-string).

Just easiest sample (for hardcoded pattern, I'm too lazy to build *any* regexp)

```
>hg grep --all DATE_FORMAT_ENTRY serendipity_lang_ru.inc.php
lang/UTF-8/serendipity_lang_ru.inc.php:9:-:@define('DATE_FORMAT_ENTRY', '%A, %e %B. %Y');
lang/UTF-8/serendipity_lang_ru.inc.php:9:+:@define('DATE_FORMAT_ENTRY', '%A, %e %B %Y');
lang/UTF-8/serendipity_lang_ru.inc.php:7:-:@define('DATE_FORMAT_ENTRY', '%A, %e %B %Y');
lang/UTF-8/serendipity_lang_ru.inc.php:7:+:@define('DATE_FORMAT_ENTRY', '%A, %e %B. %Y');
lang/UTF-8/serendipity_lang_ru.inc.php:3:-:@define('DATE_FORMAT_ENTRY', '%A, %e %B. %Y');
lang/UTF-8/serendipity_lang_ru.inc.php:3:+:@define('DATE_FORMAT_ENTRY', '%A, %e %B %Y');
lang/UTF-8/serendipity_lang_ru.inc.php:0:+:@define('DATE_FORMAT_ENTRY', '%A, %e %B. %Y');
```

(this is the most obvious output, isn't it?)